# Cannot log in, cookie related issue on the server side it seems

Tags: drupal, nginx, php

It's a fresh install of Drupal 7 via drush.

Using firebug, I can see that the cookie was sent back in the response header after I tried to log in. The page is redirected to the homepage(/node). Also the session record is saved in the session table. No error. No error on server error log either.

The same server is hosting other sites with login feature. The same browser can log in to other sites without problem. Wordpress for example. Cookie is surely enabled.

Server is running Nginx, PHP-fpm

Attached is nginx setting for my site. I am not sure if it's related to clean url. From the browser, I did see clean url. I can enter /user, /user/register, /user/password pages.

```
server
{
  listen       80;
  server_name  www.testd720.com;
  index        index.php index.html index.htm;
  root         /opt/www/drushtest/web1;
  #error_page 404 = @drupal;

  #location / {
  #          # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
  #          try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
  #          expires max;
  #}

  #location @drupal {
  #   rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
  #}

  location / {
      if (!-e $request_filename) {
          rewrite  ^/(.*)$   /index.php?q=$1  last;
          break;
      }
  }

  location ~ .*\.(php|php5)?$
  {
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include       fastcgi.conf;
  }
  access_log logs/testd720.log main;
}
```

Header:

```
Cache-Control   no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Language    en
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Thu, 07 Mar 2013 09:47:37 GMT
Etag    "1362649657"
Expires Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified   Thu, 07 Mar 2013 09:47:37 +0000
Location    http://www.testd720.com/node
Server  nginx/1.2.0
Set-Cookie  SESS26bc541d314e909277ae077251e81e7a=qu7a2apzFE9ALHnLWc04N-t_JoHhh2UCR2MkmKROVG0; expires=Sat, 30-Mar-2013 13:20:57 GMT; path=/tmp; domain=.testd720.com; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.3
```

Comment: add headers of response containing cookie, especially the cookie content (which my be restricted to a domain or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the cookie path setting:

```
Set-Cookie  SESS26bc541d314e909277ae077251e81e7a=qu7a2apzFE9ALHnLWc04N-t_JoHhh2UCR2MkmKROVG0;
   expires=Sat, 30-Mar-2013 13:20:57 GMT;
   path=/tmp;
   domain=.example.com;
   HttpOnly
```

Here you specify to your browser that this cookie should only be used on **url** on the site starting with /tmp.

You quite certainly mistakes the cookie path paramter (that is the path used to limit pths on your websites where this cookie applies) with the *cookie storage path*  on your server -- which in fact does not exists, cookies are not stored on the server -- (in php this is managed by session.save_path setting if your sessions are managed via files on the webserver, which is the default configuration, sessions are stored on the server and their name is the cookie name).